# Changing value for objects

Tags: php

When I change the values in an object I usually do like this:

**Object**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [created] => 1411033208
            [title] => test
            [description] => more test
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [created] => 1411033208
            [title] => test2
            [description] => more test 2
        )

)
```

**Code**

```
$list = array();
foreach ($entries AS $entry)
{
    $entry->created = date('Y-m-d', $entry->created);
    $list[] = $entry;
}
```

Is there a smarter way?

Comment: Why are you always reassigning `$list` to current element? And your "Object" is array of objects.

Comment: must be $list[] = $entry

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing code.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it is suppose to be $list[] = $entry;

Comment: Why exactly aren't you simply doing `foreach ($entries as $entry) $entry->created = date(...);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to store to $list or another array, you can modify it directly. Assuming that's what you're after.

```
foreach ($entries AS $entry)
{
    $entry->created = date('Y-m-d', $entry->created);
}
```

Comment: I thought ampersand was decrepeated in PHP 5.4 or something

Comment: Since objects are references by nature, the explicit reference isn't even needed.

Comment: @Cudos No, the ampersand it not deprecated. *Some specific uses* of it are, but not the whole thing in general.

Comment: Apologies, the reference is indeed not needed for objects.

Answer (score -2):

I think a smarter way would be to use magic methods within your class. The magic methods __get and __set will allow you to assign object properties at a later point in the code.

```
class GlobalClass{
    //Magic Methods
    public function __set($name, $value){
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name){
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
            return $this->data[$name];
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could make an object and assign any properties to it like so:

```
$gc = new GlobalClass();
$gc->myProperty = 'Yaaay';
```

Then use it later on like so:

```
echo $gc->myProperty;
```

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: No, it does not make sense. Because he's already doing that, without the need for setters.

Comment: Well if he wants to add more values onto the object then this does apply. However since he said 'change the values' you're quite correct.